# ProgressBar in ActionBar padding is wrong

Tags: android, android-layout

In my application I request a determinate progress bar using:

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
```

It works well but the bar does not span to the edges of the screen (see below picture). What could I do to fix this?

I compile against API v22 and I am not using appcompat.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I do not know for sure if this will resolve it or if it does, it is the perfect way to do it. I had a similar problem and i had used a negative layout_margin like below

```
android:layout_marginLeft="-22dp"
android:layout_marginRight="-22dp"
```

for the progress bar
You could try and see if this helps;-)

Comment: Thanks but where would I put this? I am not sure how to access the progress bar.